# How to take the first element of IEnumerable without iteration?

Tags: c#, iterator, ienumerable

I need to take the first element of IEnumerable, but without iteration. I used First(), but it can cause some bugs because it iterates. I know I can do it with enum, but how can I do it?

Comment: Please provide [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Okay. What is the bug?  It will be helpful if you could elaborate more about the error. FirstOrDefault(); is suggested over First()

Comment: What exactly do you want to do? First should return the first element it finds so it's not going to iterate over all elements. FirstOrDefault() will be a better choice IMO.

Comment: This question is incoherent. There is no way to enumerate an enumerable without enumerating it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`IEnumerable<T>` is what the name says, an *enumerable* thing. The only method it provides is `IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()`. Every extension method will enumerate the `IEnumerable<T>` to some extent.

If lazy evaluation/multiple enumeration is problematic (I've had that with result sets from the database, that have been evaluated after the connection has been disposed, see [here](https://gentlenerdstyle.wordpress.com/2016/06/30/the-gotchas-of-idatareader-and-linq/)), consider enumerating once, e.g. by converting the `IEnumerable<T>` to a `List<T>` with `IEnumerable<T>.ToList()`.

**Remarks**: If enumerating the enumerable causes errors, your design is flawed. Consider using another interface.

Answer (score -1):

you can try with FirstOrDefault.it stands for first element

```
int[] numbers = { };
int first = numbers.FirstOrDefault();
Console.WriteLine(first);
```